# R data.table add new column with query for each row

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 R `data.table`s in R like so:

`first_table`

```
id | first | trunc | val1
=========================
 1 |   Bob | Smith |   10
 2 |   Sue | Goldm |   20
 3 |   Sue | Wollw |   30
 4 |   Bob | Bellb |   40
```

`second_table`

```
id | first |       last | val2
==============================
 1 |   Bob |      Smith |    A
 2 |   Bob |      Smith |    B
 3 |   Sue |    Goldman |    A
 4 |   Sue |    Goldman |    B
 5 |   Sue |  Wollworth |    A
 6 |   Sue |  Wollworth |    B
 7 |   Bob | Bellbottom |    A
 8 |   Bob | Bellbottom |    B
```

As you can see, the last names in the first table are truncated. Also, the combination of first and last name is unique in the first table, but not in the second. I want to "join" on the combination of first name and last name under the incredibly naive assumptions that

- first,last uniquely defines a person
- that truncation of the last name does not introduce ambiguity.

The result should look like this:

```
id | first | trunc |       last | val1 
=======================================
 1 |   Bob | Smith |      Smith |   10
 2 |   Sue | Goldm |    Goldman |   20
 3 |   Sue | Wollw |  Wollworth |   30
 4 |   Bob | Bellb | Bellbottom |   40
```

Basically, for each row in table_1, I need to find a row that back fills the last name.

For Each Row in first_table:
    Find the first row in second_table with:
        matching first_name & trunc is a substring of last
    And then join on that row

Is there an easy vectorized way to accomplish this with `data.table`?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to join on `first`, then filter based on the substring-match

```
first_table[
    unique(second_table[, .(first, last)])
    , on = "first"
    , nomatch = 0
][
    substr(last, 1, nchar(trunc)) == trunc
]

#    id first trunc val1       last
# 1:  1   Bob Smith   10      Smith
# 2:  2   Sue Goldm   20    Goldman
# 3:  3   Sue Wollw   30  Wollworth
# 4:  4   Bob Bellb   40 Bellbottom
```

---

Or, do the truncation on the `second_table` to match the first, then join on both columns

```
first_table[
    unique(second_table[, .(first, last, trunc = substr(last, 1, 5))])
    , on = c("first", "trunc")
    , nomatch = 0
]
## yields the same answer
```